# ASP.NET MVC - Displaying the Same View again with extra information based on a radio-button selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and jQuery.

I am developing an Airline Reservation project in which I have 1 issue:-

If the Onward Flight & the Return Flight are on the same day, there should be a gap of at least 2 hours between the Onward Arrival Time & Return Departure Time. I am calling the same Select Action & passing in the Arrival Time as a parameter using :-

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/AirlineReservation/Select", data: {arrival: 
$("#arrivalTime").val()}, success: function(data)
{$("#returnPanel").show();}});
```

This code above is in the click event of the Onward Radio button.

The relevant Select Action Method Code snippet is as follows:-

```
List<String> returnTimes = new List<String>();
                    IQueryable<String> returnTimesQuery = db.Flights.Where(f => f.SectorID == returnSectorID).OrderBy(f => f.DepartureTime).Select(f => f.DepartureTime);

                    foreach (String s in returnTimesQuery)
                    {
                        if (avm.ReturnDate2 == DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString())
                        {
                            Int32 departHour = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, 2));
                            Int32 departMinute = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3, 2));

                            Int32 bookingHour = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours;
                            Int32 bookingMinute = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes;

                            TimeSpan departTime = new TimeSpan(departHour, departMinute, 0);
                            TimeSpan bookingTime = new TimeSpan(bookingHour, bookingMinute, 0);

                            TimeSpan difference = departTime - bookingTime;

                            if (difference.Hours >= 2)
                                returnTimes.Add(s);
                        }
                        else
                            returnTimes.Add(s);

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arrival))
                        {
                            if (avm.ReturnDate.Date == avm.DepartureDate.Date)
                            {
                                avm.ArrivalTime = arrival;
                                Int16 sameDayDepartHour = Convert.ToInt16(s.Substring(0, 2));
                                Int16 sameDayDepartMinute = Convert.ToInt16(s.Substring(3, 2));
                                Int16 arrivalHour = Convert.ToInt16(arrival.Substring(0, 2));
                                Int16 arrivalMinute = Convert.ToInt16(arrival.Substring(3, 2));

                                TimeSpan sameDayDepartTime = new TimeSpan(sameDayDepartHour, sameDayDepartMinute, 0);
                                TimeSpan arrivalTime = new TimeSpan(arrivalHour, arrivalMinute, 0);
                                TimeSpan sameDayDifference = sameDayDepartTime - arrivalTime;
                                if (sameDayDifference.Hours < 2)
                                    returnTimes.Remove(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }

.......................more code
```

Finally I call :-

```
return View(avm);
```

where 'avm' is the View Model instance holding all the required information.

The "returnPanel"-section of the Select-View is as follows:-

```
<div id="returnPanel" class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            @if (Model.ReturnQueryCount)
            {
                var returnQueryList = Model.ReturnQuery.ToList();

                <div class="panel-heading ">
                    <b>Returning Flight - 
@ViewBag.ReturnSplit[0].ToString() to @ViewBag.ReturnSplit[1].ToString() 
- @Model.ReturnDate2</b>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" 
id="returnTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Flight</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Departs</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Arrives</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Economy</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Business</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">First 
Class</th>
                        </tr>
                        @for (Int16 i = 0; i < Model.ReturnQuery.Count(); 
i++)
                        {

                            <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                <td style="vertical-align: 
middle;">@returnQueryList[i].FlightNumber</td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: 
middle;">@returnQueryList[i].DepartureTime</td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@returnQueryList[i].ArrivalTime</td>

                     ................more markup and razor code
```

I am adding a row to the table for each Flight in the ReturnQuery property of the Model.

The Debugging shows the correct Flights are in the ReturnQuery property, but while rendering All the Return Flights on the same day get rendered in the table after selecting an Onward Flight instead of just the pertinent ones which are present in the ReturnQuery property. Why is this happening ?

Comment: You never use the view returned by your `Select()` method. The only thing you do in the ajax success callback is show the element with `id="returnPanel"` which is the element that was initially generated when the page was first loaded. Best guess is that you want to replace that element with the view you returned?

Comment: I am new to MVC. So excuse my misunderstanding of the flow. What should be present in the ajax success callback ? The returnPanel is meant to be shown containing the available Return flights. It is initially not displayed, instead it is to be displayed only after an onward Flight has been selected.

Comment: Add an element in the main view (say) `<div id="xxx"></div>` and then in the callback - `success: function(data) { $('#xxx').html(data); }`

Comment: The returnPanel contains a table which has rows for each Flight present in the ReturnQuery property of the Model

Comment: Yes, I know - but you never do anything with it - you have not added it to the DOM

Comment: I had already tried what you have suggested and the result is that the whole View is getting reloaded and the Flight-selection in the Onward Panel is lost.

Comment: You have not shown any of the relevant code to understand what your doing here. If you only want to return some html then return just that html and add it to the DOM! I suggest you learn the basics of ajax.

Comment: Two things: 1) Why in the world are you storing times as strings in your database? Use TIME (`TimeSpan` type for your entity class). 2) Even if you insist on storing a string, you should be converting it to `TimeSpan` rather than using `Int32`s and trying to parse the string into component parts.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue as follows:-

In my Select View, I have used the following code:-

```
@if (Model.Return)
{
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Return", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "returnDiv" }, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="ArrivalTime" id="arrivalTime" />
    @Html.Partial("_OnwardView")
}
<div id="returnDiv"></div>
}
else
{
@Html.Partial("_OnwardView")
}
```

Then in the onward radio button click event handler, I have called the submit method to force the postback to make it immediately responsive:-

```
$("#submitForm").submit();
```

Finally, in the Return-Action, I have used :-

```
return PartialView("_ReturnView", avm);
```

where "avm" is the ViewModel instance containing the updated information.